# How can I extract x values from Some(x) values from a sequence of Option 'a?

Tags: f#

This one seems to be a brainer to me. I need to extract x values wrapped into Some(x) from the sequence. I can do it with

```
xs |> Seq.fold (fun state x -> match x with -> | Some(y) -> y::state | None -> state) [] 
    |> Seq.toList 
    |> List.rev 
    |> List.toSeq
```

Is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a discriminated union that isn't actually the standard Option type, you just need to supply a function to `Seq.choose` that takes an instance of your discriminated union and maps it to a standard Option. Something like...

```
xs |> Seq.choose (function Nothing _ -> None | Something x -> Some x)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is quite simple

```
xs |> Seq.choose id
```

Comment: I gotta take my time getting familiar with the standard lib :)

Comment: Ops! It turned out I need something different that that, please check the updated question. Something like xs |> Seq.Choose id |> Option.get // but it doesn't work like that

Comment: @bonomo - I don't understand - this is what I get `[Some(5);None;Some(10)] |> Seq.choose id;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [5; 10]`

Comment: @bonomo - I don't think you are using the standard `Option` type.  your `extractLinkFromNode` returns something which has `Nothing` as a constructor and the error message refers to `Optional` rather than `Option`

Comment: you are right, I made up a type similar to Option that takes an explanatory message in case of None, so standard functions are not expected to work with it, duh..

Comment: @bonomo If you are using a Non-Standard discriminated union you could do something like `Seq.filter (Function |Nothing -> false |_ -> true)`

Comment: Well this way I can filter non standard discriminated unions, but what I need is not only filter them but also extract the wrapped values after filtering.